# Output based on maximum keywords found

Tags: mysql

i have list of keyword , i want to search them against title column in my database and return one with maximum keywords :

I thought of using like but that will make query too large based on totle keywords

**test case**

I have list of keywords like :

Red,bul,win,bot,white

I have table with column title, i want to find title which has maximum number of keywords

Suppose title in my table to be like :

A **bot**tle of **red** **win**e

I have a **red** **Bul**l

The **winner** **bot**tle of **red** **Bul**l

**Bot**tle of **red** **win**e

i want output to be below one having maximum number of keywords
A **White** **bottle** of **red** **Bull**

Comment: Hi gaurav,
How many keywords do you have?

Comment: Are you using php for backend?

Comment: @VijayaVigneshKumar yes php keyword to be 4-6

Answer (score 0):

Use this method if you are using the **PHP**

Add Your keywords in array like below

```
$Arrkeywords = array('red','bul','win','bot','white');
if(count($Arrkeywords)>0) {
    $keywordcondn="";
    foreach($Arrkeywords as $keywords){
        $keywordcondn.= " and title like '%".$keywords."%'";
    }
}
$query= "SELECT * FROM `tbl_title` where title <>'' $keywordcondn";
```

Comment: From PHP you can form the  query

Comment: awaiting for your positive reply

Comment: i want result with most keywords ,not all with like